# Как построить столбчатую диаграммы на основе подсчета уникальных значений в столбце?

Tags: python, pandas, график, визуализация, диаграммы

Хочу построить столбчатую диаграмму (*Bar chart*) на основании подсчета уникальных значений в столбце:

```
count
3
2
3
1
3
1
3
2
5
3
4
3
3
3
4
3
```

Понимаю, что:

```
a = pd.unique(df['count']).tolist()
```

дает список уникальных значений, а:

```
b = df['count'].value_counts()
```

дает уникальное значение - частота его "встречания" в списке.

Как можно из этого `b` сделать именно список "встречания", чтобы можно было построить диаграмму:

```
bars = plt.bar(a, b)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проще всего использовать для этого готовую функцию библиотеки `Seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.countplot(df['count'])
```

Можно использовать и чистый `matplotlib`, но будет не так красиво выглядеть:

```
b = df['count'].value_counts()
plt.bar(b.index, b.values)
```

Answer (score 5):

Альтернативный вариант:

```
df["count"].value_counts().plot.bar(rot=0, grid=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS но решение предложенное @CrazyElf, выглядит короче и результат симпатичнее:

```
sns.countplot(df['count'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]